Keyboard unresponsive after sleep: Dell Inspiron 15 3000 running kubuntu 22.04 lts
lately I'm having a problem which is whenever my laptop goes to sleep mode and open it again the keyboard is not working and only when i restart the laptop does it work, how can i fix this?

how are you sleeping the laptop?

Through the power button or by hitting sleep from settings
